# При отправке с формы скрипт должен вернуть 3 самых длинных слова, введённые в textarea

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь это сделать, но не выдаёт мне нужный результат.

2.html

```
<form action="2.php" method="post">
<textarea name="a"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2.php

```
$a = $_POST ['a'];
include '2.html';
function getTop3($a) {

    $a = explode(' ', $a);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {

       if(mb_strlen($a[$i]) > mb_strlen($a[$i+1])) {

        $a[$i] = $a[$i+1];

       }

    }
    return (array_slice($a, 0, 3));

}
print_r(getTop3($a));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно что-то такое?

```
<?php

$words_text = 'aaa bbbbb cc ddddddddddddd eee';
$words = explode(' ', $words_text);

print_r(topThree($words));

function topThree($words){
    usort($words, 'cmp');
    return array_slice($words, count($words) - 3, 3);   
}

function cmp($a, $b){
    if( strlen($a) == strlen($b) )
        return 0;
    if (strlen($a) > strlen($b) )
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: вот только непонятно выражение count($words) - 3 в array_slice($words, count($words) - 3, 3); Можете охарактеризовать?

Comment: Т.е. почему count($words) - 3, а не count($words) - 4. Я так понимаю из документации, что последняя 3 в функции slice - это количество слов должно вернуть, а  count($words) - 3 непонятно.

Comment: @Sven, это начиная с какого элемента возвращать. То есть начинаем от третьего с конца и возвращаем три элемента.

Comment: а почему задаём именно от третьего с конца, а не с любого из всех?

Comment: Потому что слова в массиве выстроены в порядке возрастания и мы берем три самых последних (самых больших).

Comment: а..точно..они ж там после вызова usort($words, 'cmp'); выстроились уже как в пордяке возрастающих..спасибо...теперь понтяно всё!

Comment: @Sven, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'one four three eleven';
// Делим по пробельным символам.
// ВНИМАНИЕ: Знаки орфографии и прочие "не" слова останутся
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);

// Сортируем по длине строк (самые большие сначала)
usort($arr, function($a, $b){
  return mb_strlen($a) < mb_strlen($b);
});
// Брать первые 2 элемента, которые, после сортировки, самые длинные
var_dump(array_slice($arr, 0, 2));
```

https://repl.it/E8iD/0

Answer (score 0):

Основываясь на вашем коде

```
    $a = $_POST ['a'];
    include '2.html';
    function getTop3($a) {
        $a = explode(' ', $a);
        $arr = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
           if(count($arr) < 3){
              array_push($arr, $a[$i]);
           }else{
              $rw = "";
              for($t = 0; $t < count($arr); t++){
                 if(strlen($a[$i]) > strlen($arr[$t])){
                    if(strlen($arr[$t]) < strlen($rw)){
                       $rw = $t;
                    };
                 };
              };
              array_replace($arr, array($t => $a[$i]));
           };
        };
    };
    return (array_slice($arr, 0, 3));

  }
print_r(getTop3($a));
```